# InputFilter not being applied to EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, dialog

In the code below I inflate a simple layout containing 2 EditTexts and attempt to apply a Filter to them to only allow upper case(or force lower to uppercase actually) letters and numbers.  No spaces or other characters are allowed, and the lengths are fixed.  The EditText do not seem to take this filter, as both the upper case convention, and the length are ignored and I am free to enter anything I wish.  I have used similar code before, so I am lead to believe it has something to do with how I am inflating it, or that it is in the Dialog.

```
    private void createCustomNotice() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_report, null);
    builder.setView(v)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                EditText etFoo = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etxtFoo);
                InputFilter filter = new CustomTextFilter();
                etFoo.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});


                EditText etBar = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etxtBar);
                InputFilter barFilter = new FooTextFilter();
                etBar.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{barFilter, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)});


                String Foo = etFoo.getText().toString();
                String troubleCode = etBar.getText().toString();
                reportIntent(Foo.toUpperCase(), troubleCode.toUpperCase()); //Starts an intent
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    builder.create().show();
}



class CustomTextFilter implements InputFilter {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        if (source instanceof SpannableStringBuilder) {
            SpannableStringBuilder sourceAsSpannableBuilder = (SpannableStringBuilder) source;
            for (int i = end - 1; i >= start; i--) {
                char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(currentChar)
                        && !Character.isSpaceChar(currentChar)) {
                    sourceAsSpannableBuilder.delete(i, i + 1);
                }
            }
            return source.toString().toUpperCase();
        } else {
            StringBuilder filteredStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(currentChar)
                        || Character.isSpaceChar(currentChar)) {
                    filteredStringBuilder.append(currentChar);
                }
            }
            return filteredStringBuilder.toString().toUpperCase();
        }
    }

}
```

My inflated layout is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtFoo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:hint="@string/Foo_with_example"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:hint="@string/Bar_with_example"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong to cause the input filters to be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to set filters in the onClick method? This looks strange to me.
I would say move this code:

```
EditText etFoo = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etxtFoo);
InputFilter filter = new CustomTextFilter();
etFoo.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});


EditText etBar = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etxtBar);
InputFilter barFilter = new FooTextFilter();
etBar.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{barFilter, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)});
```

Just below this line:

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_report, null);
```